# Internal microphone does not work Acer Aspire Nitro VN7-592G ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, microphone, realtek

The internal microphone does not work. 
What could be the reason? 
How can I check if I have the correct driver? 
How can I verify if I have a driver at all?